# Linux opengl code doesn't work in mac os

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

This simple example of opengl. And this work fine in linux, but not draw triangle in mac os :(  What I do wrong?

For linux:

> g++ main.cpp -L /usr/local/lib/ -lglfw3 -lGLEW -lGL -lGLU -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi

For Mac OS:

> g++ main.cpp -I../../ -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wformat -framework OpenGL  -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo -L/usr/local/lib -lglfw3 -lGLEW

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;

int main( void )
{
// Initialise GLFW
if( !glfwInit() )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
    getchar();
    return -1;
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

// Open a window and create its OpenGL context
window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
if( window == NULL ){
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
    getchar();
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {

    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");

    getchar();

    glfwTerminate();

    return -1;

}

// Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

// Dark blue background
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);
static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};
GLuint vertexbuffer;


glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data),       g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

do{
    // Clear the screen. It's not mentioned before Tutorial 02, but it can cause flickering, so it's there nonetheless.
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(
0,                  
3,                  
GL_FLOAT,           
GL_FALSE,              0,                  
(void*)0            
);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); 
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();

} // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
       glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

// Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
glfwTerminate();

return 0;
}
```

Best regards.

EDIT: TY for guys! I wrote shaders and this work fine!

```
const GLchar* vertexSource =
"#version 150 core\n"
"in vec2 position;"
"void main() {"
"   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
"}";
const GLchar* fragmentSource =
"#version 150 core\n"
"out vec4 outColor;"
"void main() {"
"   outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);"
"}";
```

Comment: Where are your shaders?  No freebies in Core contexts.

Comment: That line you added "to make MacOS happy" has consequences; it gets rid of all of the deprecated functionality that let your program function under Linux (such as, as genpfault notes, rendering without GLSL shaders). Don't add code if you don't know what it does.

Comment: @genpfault, ty guys! I understand you. I should to use shader. I check this tutor http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/ and I thought that I could do it without  shaders :)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo ty too! Can you recommend a good tutorial?

Comment: [open.gl](http://open.gl) is the only one I know of that teaches core only.